# Display a truncated diff in a webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html, diff

I'm trying to display a diff of two files in a webpage using jsdiff (https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff).

Overall it works great but if there is just a small change in a huge file I do not want the entire file content to be shown, instead I want to truncate the unmodified parts. Much like diffs are displayed on github.

What I have:
AngularJS code to compute the diff using jsdiff:

```
var serverValue = selectedServiceConfig.getServerConfigDataString();
$scope.diff = JsDiff.diffLines(serverValue, newValue);
```

And then HTML:

```
<pre id="diff">
  <span ng-repeat="change in diff" ng-class="{'diff-added': change.added, 'diff-removed': change.removed, 'diff-no-change': !change.added && !change.removed}">{{change.value}}</span>
</pre>
```

And some CSS:

```
#diff {
    .diff-no-change {
        opacity: 0.54;
    }
    .diff-added{
        color: green;
    }
    .diff-removed{
        color: red;
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
}
```

This gives me for example:
[image: diff]

Now, imagine the grey parts being 1000 lines. I do not want to show it all. But rather just some of it close to an actual diff. Although, to provide context I do not want to remove it altogether which would be easy.

Hope my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

On this page of jsdiff, which describes an example, you could find out how to just display changed rows.

https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/examples/web_example.html

in the example there is following

```
var color = part.added ? 'green' :
    part.removed ? 'red' : 'grey';
```

and an comment, that 'grey' is for common parts.

so you could maybe rewrite the example, to exclude common parts

```
if (!part.added && !part.removed)
   return
```

disclaimer: i did not test anything of this, and I am not sure if this works at all. It is just the first way I would go.

Comment: Yes, although I do not want to remove all the unchanged parts. I still want some lines to provide context.

Comment: well, you can do that. But the specific implementation is your part. I will not provide a complete solution, I just mentioned how you can omit unchanged parts. And btw, I hope it helped You!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by removing the unwanted text and creating a new value in the diff object.

```
var processDiff = (diff) => {
    diff.forEach(function(part){
        if(!part.added && !part.removed){
            var lines = part.value.split('\n');
            var addedDots = false;
            part.newValue = "";
            for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
                if(i < 3 || i > lines.length-5){
                    part.newValue += lines[i] + "\n";
                }
                else if(!addedDots) {
                    part.newValue += "...\n"
                    addedDots = true;
                }
            }
            part.newValue = part.newValue.slice(0, -1)
        }
        else {
            part.newValue = part.value;
        }
    });
    return diff;
}
```

Far from perfect since I can't click on the ... to expand and the whole solution feels clumsy.

Although it gives me this look:[image: truncated diff]